# Bluetooth controller worked on Ubuntu 10.10, but not on later versions

Tags: drivers, mouse, bluetooth, touchpad

I am trying to get a Bluetooth controller working that has a touchpad, keyboard, mediabuttons etc.

In recent versions of Linux, the keyboard and mediabuttons work, but the touchpad does not, however in Ubuntu 10.04 the touchpad also worked.

I don't have much experience with Linux drivers etc, and would love to learn in order to get this working, but don't really know where to start.

Would there be a way to find out what driver the device was using and somehow get that working in later versions of Ubuntu/Linux Mint?

Please comment with any logs/command you need for more info.

dmesg on 10.04:

```
[  112.752679] input: SONY NSG-MR5-E as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/input17
[  112.753085] generic-bluetooth 0005:0609:0368.0004: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.11 Keyboard [SONY NSG-MR5-E] on 00:21:86:C0:1F:FF
```

demsg on Mint 15:

```
[  606.257698] hid-generic 0005:0609:0368.0006: unknown main item tag 0x0
[  606.258109] input: SONY NSG-MR5-E as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/input14
[  606.258314] hid-generic 0005:0609:0368.0006: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.11 Keyboard [SONY NSG-MR5-E] on e0:f8:47:1e:54:ff
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to find out what driver is being used in each case.  I don't have any bluetooth stuff, but it appears to connect via the PCI bus in your output, so this is pretty easy: `lspci -v` will list all the connected PCI devices with a line `Kernel driver in use: _____`.  If `lspci` is "not found", install the `pciutils` package.

If it's the same driver, you should probably report this as a bug, starting with the Mint crew, since it maybe a configuration issue there.  If not, they will pass it on to the kernel crew or tell you to do so.

While you are doing this, save a copy of the output from `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers` on both systems then run them through `diff`, to see what differences there are in general.